# Flash actionscript List and Dictionary<key, value> equivalents

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Does Flash Actionscript have List and Dictionary equivalents?  I've only found the documentation for the Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `List` is `Vector`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html

I don't think there's a generic (typesafe) dictionary, but the docs for `Dictionary` are: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html

Comment: There is no generic dictionary :(

Answer (score 1):

if you need a hash table with typed values, try the following:

```
  [ArrayElementType("Type")] 
    public var newTypeProperty:Array;
/*and instead of 'newTypeProperty.push();', use newTypeProperty[key] = value*/
```

it should work, but i'm lazy enough to try myself, so plz let me know if you'll get any results

Comment: Doesn't emit compile errors/warning or runtime exceptions for me.